Remove the Freehub Body from a Omnium Cargo Bike
We need to replace the freehub body of my wife's Omnium Cargo bike. We already sourced a new freehub body from the bicycle manufacturer. However, we can't remove the freehub body, it doesn't move at all.
What we already did:

removing both end caps of the axle using an end-cap removal tool
removing the bearing lock ring inside the freehub
applying a liberal amount of rust remover and waiting.

What we tried so far:

pulling on the freehub body (in all videos, it seems like it should come off without any effort at all)
adding a single cassette sprocket to the freehub and pulling really hard on the freehub with this additional "grip"

How can we possibly remove the old freehub body?

The old freehub

Front View

Opposite (non-drive) side

New original freehub body for reference

Okay, after some more steps, the freehub came off.

using a soft-faced hammer, hit the shaft from the non-drive side.
it may pop out with the whole freehub assembly still attached to it.
You can now lever the freehub body from the shaft using the ridge between the drive side bearing and the freehub, using e.g. a flathead screw driver.


Apply leverage from here.

Excellent work!  Thank you for providing your solution for future readers too.
